# Given a list of integer numbers and a list of indices how can i use map to add 10 to specific elements in the first list?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I want to map a function only to specific elements in a list; those would be the elements of the indices existent in the indices list. I have tried lots of things similar to what I've written here, below. I am trying to achieve this without using the classic for-loop. *edit: by "classic for-loop" I mean using range ( something like: for i in range(len(list)) )

```
lista = [123, 456, 1, 0, -2, 13, 15, 29, 47, 48]
index_list = [0, 1, 2, 3]
lista = list( map( lambda x: x + 10 if #some condition here I could not figure out#
\ else x for x in list ) ) 
print(lista) 
#expected output: [133, 466, 11, 10, -2, 13, 15, 29, 47, 48]
```

I have also tried defining my own function and then mapping it, but to no avail. How can I do this?

Comment: Does it have to be list-comprehension?

Comment: not necessarilly; would appreciate any solution at the moment; definitely curious about a non-list-comprehension solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you don't want to use the straight forward solution by iterating the indices list instead:

The problem is that one of the variables you're depending on (the index) is not included in your call to `map`. You'll have to insert that into the map call in some way, for example by using `enumerate` - which will emit a `(idx, value)` tuple for each element in your list.

```
nums = [123, 456, 1, 0, -2, 13, 15, 29, 47, 48]
indices = [0, 1, 2, 3]

result = list(
    map(
        lambda x: x[1] + 10 if x[0] in indices else x[1],
        enumerate(nums)
    )
)

print(result)
```

Be aware that the `if x[0] in indices` part will search the indices list linearly, and will make the whole operation `O(n * m)`. This can be optimised by using a set (which has O(1) lookup as the common case) or a dictionary instead.

```
> [133, 466, 11, 10, -2, 13, 15, 29, 47, 48]
```